# Разумно ли использовать следующий вид форматирования вывода на Java?

Tags: java, массивы, print, форматирование

Я имею ввиду, с точки зрения изящности кода. Или все эти запятые, да скобки поместить как-то в print? Ума не приложу как оптимизировать - что б красиво было.
**Использование Collections не предлагать!!!**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int massiv[] = new int[20];
    System.out.print("["); // здесь первая скобка
    for (int i = 0; i < massiv.length; i++) {
        massiv[i] = sluchaynoeCeloe();
        System.out.print(massiv[i] + ", "); // собственно, запятые
        if (i == massiv.length - 1) // это вообще стыдно показывать
            System.out.print(massiv[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("]"); // ну и, последний штрих!
}

public static int sluchaynoeCeloe() {
    int a = -7, b = 13;
    return (int)(Math.random() * (b + (Math.abs(a) + 1))) - Math.abs(a);
}
```

Выведет так:

```
[3, 4, 6, 12, 2, 10, -1, -5, 4, 13, 11, -6, 8, -6, 12, 0, 5, 7, 1, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать стандартное поведение из [Arrays.toString(Object[] array)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[]))

А там написано так

```
public static String toString(Object[] a) {
    if (a == null)
        return "null";
    int iMax = a.length - 1;
    if (iMax == -1)
        return "[]";
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    b.append('[');
    for (int i = 0;; i++) {
        b.append(String.valueOf(a[i]));
        if (i == iMax)
            return b.append(']').toString();
        b.append(", ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Код в вопросе вообще работает неверно:

> ```
> if (i == massiv.length - 1) // это вообще стыдно показывать
>     System.out.print(massiv[i]);
> ```

Здесь последнее число выводится повторно. http://ideone.com/tOYrbS

---

Под условие надо помещать вывод разделителя. И я бы сравнивал с нулём, а не с длиной:

http://ideone.com/cBQsc4

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int massiv[] = new int[20];

    System.out.print("[");

    for (int i = 0; i < massiv.length; i++) {
        massiv[i] = sluchaynoeCeloe();

        if (i != 0) {
            System.out.print(", ");
        }

        System.out.print(massiv[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("]");
}
```

---

Ну и, как уже сказали во всех ответах, стоит воспользоваться `Arrays.toString`:

http://ideone.com/1Pp7J2

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int massiv[] = new int[20];

    for (int i = 0; i < massiv.length; i++) {
        massiv[i] = sluchaynoeCeloe();
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(massiv));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться методом `toString(...)` класса `Arrays`.

Например, код:

```
int[] a = new int[5];
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

Выведет:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы в первую очередь разделил инициализацию и вывод.

```
int massiv[] = new int[20];
for (int i = 0; i < massiv.length; i++) {
    massiv[i] = sluchaynoeCeloe();
}
```

А дальше очень просто:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(massiv));
```

Вывод подсмотрел [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int massiv[] = new int[20];
    System.out.print("[");

                            // разделитель элементов массива. 
    String razdelitel = ""; // сначала перед первым элементом пустой

    for (int i = 0; i < massiv.length; i++) {
        massiv[i] = sluchaynoeCeloe();

        System.out.print(razdelitel + massiv[i]);

        razdelitel = ", ";  // после первого элемента разделитель всегда ", "

        // или с условием: if (razdelitel.isEmpty()) razdelitel = ", ";
    }
    System.out.println("]");
}
```